# GIT Commands Flow

Tags: git, github

I have started git in my new project, Here I have some doubts that I want to know. I first took the clone of the repo, then I'll have all codebase in my local with default branch on master. Somewhere its written we need to delete or rename the local master branch why?

I use below steps for any new feature suppose local master is at it is.

```
    git checkout -b new-branch
    (same changes done in code files)
    git add .
    git commit -m "Comment Commited"
    git push origin new-branch
    (Now the reviewer will review the code and after incorporated review comment)
    git checkout master
    git pull origin master
    git merge new-branch
    git push origin master
```

Now here question comes, If the changes merged in the origin master. then what will be of the new-branch that is on local and remote both. Shall I need to delete these branches?
Also Are these steps that I written are well enough to start on GIT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature branch `new-branch` will still reside locally and remotely. If the branch is no longer needed you will want to delete it (`git branch -d new-branch` and `git push origin :new-branch`).

You may wish to take a look at [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). It will automate the clean up of feature branches for you, as well as help to create some separation between development and production code.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the ideal flow , creating a short term branch or a hotfix branch , merge to the master/dev branch and deleting the same afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Yes the flow is correct and and good to go.You want to keep your branches or not depends on the flow of your project.As you have merged your branch  with master so same can be deleted,if branch was created only to fix some issue.
Other then this if you want to keep this as a tag in your environment so that you can easily deploy different versions of code then you can keep that.[don't mix this with actual tagging capability of git]

Keeping branches is not expensive in git as only pointers are created which point to the main code line but we see them as branches.